# Getting first number from string

Tags: string

The following function fails to return "16":

```
(string-to-number "bm16")
```

It seems to get tripped up if the first characters of a string aren't numbers.  Is there a way to construct an elisp function which takes a string of text and returns the number it contains (it doesn't have to handle decimals)?

Comment: There is no function named `first-number-from-string` in my emacs: how is it defined? where did you get it from?

Comment: NickD: My mistake. I meant `string-to-number`.

Comment: What should happen for the string "abcdef" which contains no digits? And do you want the result to be a number or its string representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible implementation: find the first digit, get the substring of the original string that starts at that first digit and *then* call `string-to-number` on the result:

```el
(defun first-number-of-string (s)
  (string-to-number (substring s (string-match-p "[0-9]" s))))

(first-number-of-string "bm16" -> 16
(first-number-of-string "abc123def456" -> 123
(first-number-of-string "abc123") -> 123
(first-number-of-string "123def") -> 123
(first-number-of-string "123") -> 123
(first-number-of-string "abcdef") -> 0
```

That's assuming that the answers to the questions in my comment are that you indeed want a number, not its string representation, and in the case where there is no number in the string, having the function return `0` is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using cl functions:

```
(defun first-number-in-string(s)
   (string-to-number
     (seq-take-while
     #'cl-digit-char-p 
     (seq-drop-while
      (lambda(x)(not (cl-digit-char-p x)))
      s))))

    (mapcar #'first-number-in-string 
'( "bm16" "abc123def456" "abc123" "123def" "123" "abcdef")) 
=>     (16 123 123 123 123 0)
```

The same algorithm splitted for clarity::

```
(defun collect-first (pred coll)
  (seq-take-while pred
                  (seq-drop-while (lambda (x) (not(funcall pred x)))
                                  coll)))


(defun first-number-in-string(s)
   (string-to-number
     (collect-first #'cl-digit-char-p  s)))
```